# Error in production ActionView::Template::Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I created an application where an user can create Max Rep of weight lifted. It works pretty well in development but when it goes to production it gives me the following error when i try to crete a new RM:

> Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 8ms (ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)
>   ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `quantity' for #
>   Rm:0x007ffa2bf0cb48

I would like to now why and how i can fix this.

New form of RM:

```
  <div class="col-md-12 col-md-offset-3">
<%= form_for([@user, @rm]) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <%= f.select :content, ['Back squat', 'Front squat', 'Deadlift',
                          'Sumo Deadlift', 'Sumo Deadlift High Pull',
                          'Power Snatch', 'Power Clean',
                          'Squat Clean', 'Muscle Snatch',
                          'Clean & Jerk', 'Thruster', 'Push Jerk',
                          'Split Jerk', 'Press',
                          'Push press', 'Cluster', 'Overhead Squat']%>



  <%= f.label :quantity, "Peso levantado" %>
  <%= f.number_field :quantity %>

  <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>

  <%= f.submit "Crear", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

RM controller:

```
class RmsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]
  before_action :load_user, only: [:create, :destroy]

  def new
    @rm = Rm.new
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])

  end

  def create
    @rm = @user.rms.build(rms_params)
    if @rm.save
      flash[:success] = "Repeticion maxima creada"
      redirect_to user_rms_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def index
    @rms = Rm.where(user_id: params[:user_id])
  end

  def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    Rm.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "Repeticion maxima eliminada"
    redirect_to user_rms_path
  end


  private
    def rms_params
      params.require(:rm).permit(:user_id, :content, :quantity)
    end

    def load_user
      @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    end
  end
```

Comment: You might be missing a migration, that is `quantity` doesn't exist in the production db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run `rails db:migrate:status` to see if you have some pending migrations.

Or if you by any chance forgot to add that column you can use the rails console (I think the fastest way) to check if the model has such attribute, you can run `heroku run rails console` and then inside to check with `Rm.new` and to see if those attributes coincide with your actual code.